# Wrapping mutate within logic function to use with lapply

Tags: r, logic, lapply, dplyr

I've just started learning how to use lapply. I am looking to read a folder of csv, mutate them to create a variable `state` (which is based on the label of the file name), and then bind them altogether.

However, I'm a little stumped on the `mutate` part of this process. I looked through a few posts and it seems like the easiest way to do this is to wrap my commands into a logic function and then parse them with lapply.

This is what I did:

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

path<-"~/Downloads/Postings CSV"
read_report_data <- function(path) {
  report_df <- read.csv(path)
  report_df<-mutate(report_df, state=substring(report_df, 20, nchar(report_df) - 9))
}
reports <- lapply(file_list, read_report_data)%>% 
bind_rows
```

However, I'm receiving this traceback error:

```
 Error: Column `state` must be length 726 (the number of rows) or one, not 8
```

Not sure what I did to receive this error. Your help is greatly appreciated

**Suggestion that worked**

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

path<-"~/Downloads/Postings CSV"
read_report_data <- function(path) {
  report_df <- read.csv(path)
  mutate(report_df, state = substring(path, 20, nchar(path) - 9))
}
library(purrr)
map_dfr(file_list, read_report_data, full.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: I wouldn't think that would make a difference; `mutate` returns the full frame, and since it's the last assignment in the function, it is the implicit return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function, the `substring` should not be on the full dataset.  It can be on a single column or here, it makes sense to get the `substring` of path

```
read_report_data <- function(path) {
    report_df <- read.csv(path)
    mutate(report_df, state = substring(path, 20, nchar(path) - 9))
 }
```

Now, we can use `map_dfr`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(file_list, read_report_data)
```

Comment: @YuNa perhaps you need `full.names = TRUE`

Comment: @YuNA Can you show the values of `file_list`.  If the `length` is more than 1, `map` is looping over each element, read the data within the funciton, create a new column, and the suffix `_dfr` makes sure the `list` output is rbinded to have a single data.frame

Comment: @YuNa As I mentioned, the solution is based on your code.  I cannot test it without a reproducble example.  In general, the code shouldd work if the file names are ccorrect

Comment: As it turns out, I was just viewing the wrong dataframe. This worked like a charm. Thanks for your patience